# If Lie subgroup weakly embeded(initial) submanifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $ G $ be a Lie group and $ H\subset G $ be a Lie subgroup, which is itself a Lie group and an immersed submanifold of $ G $. Is the following correct:

for any smooth map $ f:M\to G $ where $ M $ is a smooth manifold, if the image of $ f $ lies in $ H $, then $ \hat{f}:M\to H $ is continuous(and consequently smooth) when $ H $ is regarded as the immersed submanifold of $ G $(this is just the definition of being weakly embedded)?

Comment: Are you asking whether Lie subgroups are always weakly embedded? If yes, then this is indeed true. A proof can be found in Lee's Introduction to manifolds, theorem 19.25.

Comment: @Grep: yes, thank you very much.